# UAG Reverse Proxy ... but strip the "Proxy Pattern"

Tags: vmware-uag

So I'm trying to set up a VMWare Unified Access Gateway reverse proxy.  The issue I'm currently having is that then entire "Proxy Pattern" is sent to the internal host.  What I'd really like to do is set the "Proxy Pattern" to (let's say) /proxy ... but **not** send that part to the internal host.

So for example, if I configure the Proxy Pattern to

```
/proxy
```

then a URL

```
httpx://uag.mycompany.com/proxy/foobar
```

should be proxied to

```
httpx://internal.mycompany.com/foobar
```

Is that possible?  If it is, I can't find it in the documentation that I have.

(Side note -- this is **not** an X-Y issue.  I'm trying to workaround a UAG limitation where I need to proxy to a specific port while keeping the naming scheme intact.)

Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure the proxy pattern?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider The proxy pattern is `/proxy`

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `/proxy(.*)`, as in the examples in the documentation? I would expect the capture group to act as the placeholder for the part that should be proxied.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider No luck.  I'm still seeing `path=/proxy/` in my logs.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider  I just found https://docs.vmware.com/en/Unified-Access-Gateway/2306/uag-deploy-config/GUID-E4C155B6-112A-4A7E-AC53-96F72781AEDD.html which says "Simple proxy patterns are case sensitive. Page links and proxy patterns must match. "

Answer (score 0):

I just found

https://docs.vmware.com/en/Unified-Access-Gateway/2306/uag-deploy-config/GUID-E4C155B6-112A-4A7E-AC53-96F72781AEDD.html

which says

> Simple proxy patterns are case sensitive. **Page links and proxy patterns must match.**

So apparently, what I want is not possible. :(

Comment: Why should it not be possible? Your examples show no problem with case sensitivity. Your question lacks details.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider   It says "Page links and proxy patterns must match.".  My page links do not match my proxy patterns.

Comment: Answer updated for emphasis

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).